# Should I allow new, unknown INCOMING traffic (svchost.exe) from 10.0.0.x to 10.0.0.y, where y is my IP address?

Tags: firewall, lan, comodo-firewall

I have Comcast/Xfinity internet, and I am the only connection in the house.  Wifi connection to the Xfinity modem/router.

Recently, there are incoming connection requests from 10.0.0.x (x is a static number) to 10.0.0.y (y makes this my IP address) through svchost.exe. It's a UDP connection (incoming port 37447, outgoing port 56538).

I haven't needed to update anything in my firewall for a few months.

Should I allow this new traffic?

I looked this up and 10.*.*.* is private address space for local LANS.  I haven't set up a LAN.

Comment: How exactly are you connected to the internet? A router? A modem? Traffic isn’t directed at programs but rather at ports (with TCP and UDP at least). Can you see which port the remote host is trying to reach? The protocol (TCP/UDP/ICMP/whatever) is also relevant.

Comment: @DanielB The Xfinity coax cable goes to a Modem/Router.  I connect via Wi-Fi.   It's a UDP connection. Incoming port: 37447, outgoing port 56538.

Comment: Port 37447 is not known for any particular use. Can you check whether anything is actually listening on that port on your PC? (You can use Sysinternals TCPView to do so.) Your firewall may be making… “sensationalist claims”.

Comment: @DanielB  I don't get any Google results for 'firewall "sensationalist claims”'